# PROMQL Query to determine Pod resource and limits

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, promql

We have our web api service running in OpenShift for the past few months

When we deployed this to OpenShift, initially we have given basic request and limits for memory and CPU.

Sometime when the resource limit crossed its threshold we had to increase the limit

We have several services deployed and we have given some random request and limits for the Pod.
we are trying to figure out a way to provide resource limits and request based on the past few months that it is running on OpenShift

My idea is to look at the last few months on requests what is POD is receiving and come up with a value to requests and limits

I am thinking PROMQL can help me to provide this value, can someone help me with a query to determine average resource and limits based on past 4 to 5 weeks of requests on the POD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below queries which are helpful in your case :

```
avg (  
  avg_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:rate5m[30d])
) by (pod_name)
```

The above query is used  to determine the average CPU usage of a certain pod for the past 30 days.

```
avg (  
  avg_over_time(container_memory_usage_seconds_total:rate5m[30d])
) by (pod_name)
```

The above query is used  to determine the average memory usage of a certain pod for the past 30 days.

In the query avg is used to calculate the average of the sample values in the input series, grouped by their `[pod_name]`. `avg_over_time` is used for getting the average value of all points in the specified interval, we can get the metrics like cpu and memory usage for the specified interval by using the respective queries.

For more info follow this [doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time).

Comment: The above query will help in calculating the average for Limits, but for request I dont think we have to take the average, we have to take the minimum, which query could help me in this case

Comment: It says no datapoints foud, I am running this query in OpenShift. And also why are you calculating using average, for resource.requests it should the minimum required value right ?

Comment: There was a little confusion, for requests we need to use sum as we are trying to find the total no.of requests handled, now try `sum (rate (http_requests_total[30d])) by (pod_name)` this will help in your case. Here is a [git](https://gist.github.com/max-rocket-internet/6a05ee757b6587668a1de8a5c177728b) link for more info.

Comment: Thanks Sai, there was a mistake from myside, what I meant was regarding requests.cpu and request.memory,   I am using sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[1h])) by (namespace, pod) to calculate requests.cpu is this correct, it shows in decimal values like 0.009386754, how can I convert it to millicore ?

Comment: To convert these requests.cpu value to millicores, you can multiply the result by 1000. For example, if the result of the expression is 0.009386754, you can multiply it by 1000 to get 9.386754 millicores.